# Regular Expression for Finding Numbers in a Line (Python)

Tags: python

I'm just learning about regular expressions and I need to read in a text file and find every instance of a number and find the sum of all the numbers.

```
import re

sum = 0
list_of_numbers = list()
working_file = open("sample.txt", 'r')
for line in working_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    working_list = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if len(working_list) != 1:
        continue
    print(working_list)
    for number in working_list:
        num = int(number)
        list_of_numbers.append(num)
for number in list_of_numbers:
    sum += number
print(sum)
```

I put the `print(working_list)` in order to try and debug it and see if all the numbers are getting found correctly and I've seen, by manually scanning the text file, that some numbers are being skipped while others are not. I'm confused as to why as I thought my regular expression guaranteed that any string with any amount of digits will be added to the list.

[Here is the file](http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt).

Comment: `if len(working_list) != 1` ... im pretty sure thats not what you want... note you *really dont even have to check if the `working_list` has numbers at all...

Comment: so, you just need to do `total = sum(int(x) for line in working_file for x in re.findall('[0-9]+', line))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only validating lines that have ONLY one number, so a line with two numbers will be skipped because of `if len(working_list) != 1: continue`, that basically says "if there isn't EXACTLY one number on this line then skip", you may have meant something like `if len(working_list) < 1: continue`

Comment: Oh wow! Silly error on my part I don't know how I didn't see that! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
import re

digits_re = re.compile(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)') 
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as fh:
  numbers = [float(match[0]) for match in digits_re.findall(fh.read())]
print(sum(numbers))
```

or like you're doing with ints just

```
import re

digits_re = re.compile(r'(\d+)') 
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as fh:
  numbers = [int(match[0]) for match in digits_re.findall(fh.read())]
print(sum(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = open('file.txt')
nos = list()
for ln in h:
    fi = re.findall('[0-9]+', ln)
    for i in fi:
        nos.append(int(i))
print('Sum:', sum(nos))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.